# Webix Comment UI Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, webix

I'm quite new to webix, does anyone knows if a comment UI supports lazy loading?
unlike datatable and dataview that supports it, it looks like webix comment ui doesn't 
I just need a reference on how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load comments in portions https://docs.webix.com/desktop__comments.html#loadingcommentsondemand

This is a package example of how to load comments in portions and load more on demand:

- snippet https://snippet.webix.com/ww82u48f
- docs catalogue https://docs.webix.com/samples/30_comments/11_more_comments.html

In the Webix package, you will find the example of backend code in /backend/comments/index.js